# How to switch button position on mobiles and tables?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 pt-2 d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-md-end">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2 mb-md-0 mr-md-2">Back</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When displayed on smaller devices, the buttons occupy the whole width. This is as expected.

However, I would like that when this happens, the `Next` button is displayed above the `Back` button.

Is this possible?

Comment: What did you try? You could simply use `flex-column-reverse` instead of `flex-column`, but you'll have to adjust the margins.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can then use media breakpoints to change css.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .btn-secondary{
        order: 1;
   }
  .btn-primary{
       margin-bottom: 0.5rem !important;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).